# Biblatex non-standard date

Tags: biblatex

I'm using biblatex and biber for referencing works beeing showed in an history lesson. 
Datation in centuries (12th century or *12e siècle* in french) are quite common. I used to write such dates in the field "Year", and it worked since the last upgrade:

Folowing MWE compiles with TexLive 2015…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @Thesis{exemple_image,
    Title                    = {Title of the work},
    Author                   = {Artist Name},
    Location                 = {Switzerland},
    Year                     = {{\siecle{15}}},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newcommand{\siecle}[1]{%
\textsc{\romannumeral #1}\textsuperscript{e}~siècle
}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: reference correctly printed]

…but not anymore with TexLive 2016, where I've got an error: `! Use of /sortlist doesn't match its definition`.

I guess Biblatex 3.5 is less permissive with the "Year" field. I've searched in the documentation without success and I'm open to all suggestions.

Comment: If you're not sorting by date, then the easiest thing to do is to use another field, such as `addendum`.

Comment: Thank you, yes I could do it, but if I have to change all my .bib files, I would prefer too have another solution, like writing 15uu in the "date" field and change some biblatex commands to print it the right way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the new ISO 8601 date features of `biblatex` 3.10 and above you can input a century as

```
date = {19XX}
```

Unfortunately, the standard date formats do not deal with this out of the box by showing '20th century' or similar output, they'd just write '1900-1999',  but we can enable handling of centuries as follows

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@thesis{exemple_image,
  title    = {Title of the work},
  author   = {Artist Name},
  location = {Switzerland},
  date     = {16XX},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\NewBibliographyString{century}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{century = {siècle}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\RNfont}{\textsc}
\DeclareFieldFormat{datecentury}{\RN{#1}\textsuperscript{e}}
\renewrobustcmd*{\mkdaterangetrunc}[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \blx@metadateinfo{#2}%
    \iffieldundef{#2year}
      {}
      {\printtext[#2date]{%
         \datecircaprint
         % Such a season component can only come from an EDTF 5.1.5 season which replaces
         % a normal month so if it exists, we know that a normal date print is ruled out
         \iffieldequalstr{dateunspecified}{yearincentury}
           {\printtext[datecentury]{\number\numexpr\thefield{#2year}/100+1\relax}\setunit{\addnbspace}\bibstring{century}}
           {\iffieldundef{#2season}
              {\iffieldsequal{#2year}{#2endyear}
                 {\iffieldsequal{#2month}{#2endmonth}
                    {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{}{}{#2day}}
                    {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{}{#2month}{#2day}}}
                 {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{#2year}{#2month}{#2day}%
                  \iffieldsequal{#2dateera}{#2enddateera}{}
                   {\dateeraprint{#2year}}}}
              {\iffieldsequal{#2year}{#2endyear}
                {\csuse{mkbibseasondate#1}{}{#2season}}
                {\csuse{mkbibseasondate#1}{#2year}{#2season}%
                 \iffieldsequal{#2dateera}{#2enddateera}{}
                   {\dateeraprint{#2year}}}}%
            \dateuncertainprint
            \iffieldundef{#2endyear}
              {}
              {\iffieldequalstr{#2endyear}{}
                 {\mbox{\bibdaterangesep}}
                 {\bibdaterangesep
                  \enddatecircaprint
                  \iffieldundef{#2season}
                    {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{#2endyear}{#2endmonth}{#2endday}}
                    {\csuse{mkbibseasondate#1}{#2endyear}{#2endseason}}%
                  \enddateuncertainprint
                  \dateeraprint{#2endyear}}}}}}%
  \endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Where `\iffieldequalstr{dateunspecified}{yearincentury}` checks for a century, the format `datecentury` controls the output of the century and the bibstring `century` can be used to localise the output further.

[image: example output]

Refer also to [`96-dates.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/96-dates.tex) as well as §2.3.8 *Date and Time Specifications*, §4.2.4.1 *Generic Fields* of [the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

Comment: Thx a lot, I've made a `\renewbibmacro*{date}…` from your answer and it works perfectly. I'm now cleaning my .bib files adopting the EDTF norm. The more I understand biblatex the more I enjoy it!

Comment: @omisson Glad to hear that it works for you. The solution should work more or less out of the box, I don't see why you should have to `\renewbibmacro*{date}`, did the redefinition of `\mkdaterangetrunc` not work for you?

Comment: It works out of the box. It's just I'm writing a cls and I prefere not to write code I don't understand. I don't know what `mkdaterangetrunc` is doing. It's not in the documentation. Are there some reason not to redefine the bibmacro? (I'm already doing it to print origdate).

Comment: @omisson `\mkdaterangetrunc` is some intermediate macro and that change would then work for most dates, not only those printed by `\usebibmacro{date}`.

Comment: Since biblatex 3.11, `date = {19XX}` should be used, perhaps could you update your answere.

Comment: @omisson Done. There were also a few tweaks to the `\mkdaterangetrunc` macro that should be applied.

Answer (score 7):

Just change the way you define `\siecle`:

```
\newrobustcmd{\siecle}[1]{%
  \textsc{\romannumeral #1}\textsuperscript{e}~siècle
}
```

In such a way the macro is not expanded prematurely. Of course, the warning

```
WARN - year field '{\siecle{15}}' in entry 'exemple_image' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.
```

will show nonetheless.

[image]

Comment: Thx it works perfectly and I can now upgrade to TexLive 2016. Biblatex 3.5 has some surprises, but a lot of possibilities, I'm reading the documentation about dates.

Comment: With  `sortyear = {1600}` the warning should disappear, because `sortyear` is the considered for sorting, but I think there was a bug with that that is only resolved in the upcoming version 2.8 of Biber.

Comment: This solution is still very useful, for special dates like "first quarter of the 12th Century" for example.  I'd like to vote for both!

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to rely on Biber to map the `year` field to another field. (This example uses `addendum`.) It is unclear from the example as to whether you want or need to limit the sourcemapping to a specific sub-set of entries, but there are a number of ways to do this. (This example limits to the specific `.bib` file and the entrytype `thesis`, just as an example.)

Biber will finish without warnings or errors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @Thesis{exemple_image,
    Title                    = {Title of the work},
    Author                   = {Artist Name},
    Location                 = {Switzerland},
    Year                     = {{\siecle{15}}},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newcommand{\siecle}[1]{%
  \textsc{\romannumeral #1}\textsuperscript{e}~siècle
}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
    \map{
      \perdatasource{\jobname.bib}% <-- If you have them in a special bib file
      \pertype{thesis}%             <-- If you want to limit by type
      \step[fieldsource=year]
      \step[fieldset=addendum, origfieldval]
      \step[fieldset=year, null]
    }
  }
}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```